# Kali linux mouse and keyboard stopped working after apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Tags: linux, keyboard, touchpad

I'm running Kali on a mid-2012 MacBook Pro, and I haven't had any problems with persistence until I ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade yesterday and rebooted my computer only to find that the built-in touchpad and keyboard no longer work. Booting into Kali live works fine, but I need to be using persistence.

Running Kali 2018.1, 32-bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: ask in linux community i think this question doesn't belong here

Comment: @jasinth premkumar how does this not belong here? Does it not have to do with computer hardware or software?

Comment: What version of Kali is this? Are you on Kali rolling? What version and year please.

Comment: Not sure about rolling, but the version is 2018.1, 32-bit (picked for greater compatibility across machines).

Comment: Maybe see https://www.infoworld.com/article/3060814/linux/should-beginners-install-kali-linux-on-their-computers.html and related topics e.g. on [unix.se]: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: That's utterly unhelpful. I'm well familiar with linux, and I've never encountered a problem like this before, and I have not been able to find any thread on it despite hours of Googling.